# How do I get the total retries on a background job in Hangfire from the PerformContext?

Tags: c#, hangfire

From this post:

[How do I get the current attempt number on a background job in Hangfire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368153/how-do-i-get-the-current-attempt-number-on-a-background-job-in-hangfire)

It is possible to get the retry count by using the magic string "RetryCount".

```cs
public void SendEmail(PerformContext context, string emailAddress)
{
   string jobId = context.BackgroundJob.Id;
   int retryCount = context.GetJobParameter<int>("RetryCount");
   // send an email
}
```

How about if I need to get the total retry number?
Can I use something like:

```cs
int retries = context.GetJobParameter<int>("Retries");
```

Or how can I get that info from the "PerformContext" (if possible at all)?

I need the total retries defined thus I can perform some tasks on the last retry.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `AutomaticRetryAttribute` to define the number of retry attempts on a method then something like the following will work:

```
var retryAttempts = context.BackgroundJob.Job.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutomaticRetryAttribute), false)
    .Cast<AutomaticRetryAttribute>()
    .Select(a => a.Attempts)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If the attribute is not present then this will return `0`. This will not help if the maximum number of retries is set globally or modified in the attribute at a later date.